# Extract only key names from JSON in array format using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How to get JSON data key names in a array format using nodejs?

I've tried the following but it returns object. But I want an array so I can store it in a varaible.

```
const jsondata = [{ "name": "StorageType", "value": "AllStorageTypes" }, { "name": "BucketName", "value": "testing" }]

Object.keys(jsondata).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = jsondata[key];
  console.log(value)
});
```

`output:`

```
{ name: 'StorageType', value: 'AllStorageTypes' }
{ name: 'BucketName', value: 'testing' }
```

`Expected output:`

```
["StorageType", "BucketName"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
const jsondata = [{ "name": "StorageType", "value": "AllStorageTypes" }, { "name": "BucketName", "value": "testing" }]

const arrayData = jsondata.map(item => item.name)
console.log(arrayData)
```

Answer (score 2):

`jsondata.map(obj=>obj.name)`